# Convert categorical variable into binary columns in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, categorical

I made the stupid mistake of enabling people to select multiple categories in a survey question.

Now the data column for this question looks something along the lines of this.

| respondent | answer_openq |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a,c |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | a,d |

using the following line in r,

```
datanum <- data %>% mutate(dummy=1) %>%
spread(key=answer_openq,value=dummy, fill=0)
```

I get the following:
[image: data how it looks like now]

However, I want the dataset to transform into this:

| respondent | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Any help is appreciated (my thesis depends on it). Thanks :)

Comment: I like `splitstackshape` for these operations. For your case, `splitstackshape::cSplit_e(df, 'answer_openq', ',', type= 'character', fill=0, drop=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  separate_rows(answer_openq, sep = ',') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = answer_openq, values_from = answer_openq, 
              values_fn = function(x) 1, values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  respondent     a     c     b     d
       <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1          1     1     0     0     0
2          2     1     1     0     0
3          3     0     0     1     0
4          4     1     0     0     1
```